# Something is wrong with database display data clientside

Tags: php, mysql, foreign-keys

I'm building this CRM and I'm running into a bit of a weird situation when writing a query to display tables data client-side. I have hard time understanding how to fix it... I did delete a foreign key in a different table prior to encountering this issue because I wanted to modify the primary row and now I guess im paying the price I don't know what to do... Client-side how the data display is really not matching whats in database... Anyways i'm ready to get eaten alive... I'm a NOOB i'm learning the hard way and I also write PHP like im a noob so my code does look noobish but it works for me and that's how I understand it. So If you have any tips how to fix this that'd be great...

The problem is the following : The ID row client-side does not return the one in the database and the names who the message was sent to is not matching the ones in the database. I suspect it has something to do with the id from which I deleted the foreign key...

**database side | sentmessages table**
[image]

**client-side**

[image]

**mailmessages.php**

```
 <!-- 
================================================================
Sent Messages 
================================================================
-->
<?php

$perpage=5;
if(isset($_GET['page'])){
    $page=$_GET['page'];
}
else{
    $page=1;
}  



$offset=($page-1)*$perpage;
$sqlsent="SELECT * FROM sentmessages INNER JOIN employees ON sentmessages.toEmployee_id=employees.employee_id WHERE username = '$user_check' LIMIT ".$offset.",".$perpage."";
$resultsent=mysqli_query($db,$sqlsent);
?>
       <table id="table" class="sortable rwd-table table table-striped table-hover tablesorter " >

      <thead style="cursor:pointer;">
          <th>ID</th>
        <th>Date Sent</th>
          <th>To</th>
        <th>Subject</th>
            <th style='visibility: hidden;'>Message</th>
     </thead>

     <tbody>
    <?php while ($sent = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultsent)) {?>
      <tr>
           <td data-th="ID"><?=$sent['id'];?></td>
              <td data-th="Date Sent"><?=$sent['time'];?></td>

              <?php $toEmployee_idfnln ="SELECT first_name, last_name FROM employees INNER JOIN sentmessages ON employees.employee_id=sentmessages.toEmployee_id WHERE username=employees.username";$resulfnln=mysqli_query($db,$toEmployee_idfnln);$displaynames = $resulfnln->fetch_assoc();?>
        <td data-th="To"><?=$displaynames['first_name'];?> <?=$displaynames['last_name'];?></td>

        <td data-th="Subject"><?=$sent['subject'];?></td>
        <td data-th="Message"><i class="fa fa-eye optionbox" aria-hidden="true"></i> <i class="fa fa-trash optionbox" aria-hidden="true"></i></td>
      </tr>
        <?php };?>
     </tbody>
     <tfoot></tfoot>


    </table>


           <div class='col-md-6 pull-left'>
               <p>Total : 
                   <?php $sqlsentmsg="SELECT * FROM sentmessages INNER JOIN employees ON sentmessages.toEmployee_id=employees.employee_id WHERE username = '$user_check'"; $resultsentmsg=mysqli_query($db,$sqlsentmsg); $rowcountmsg=mysqli_num_rows($resultsentmsg);echo $rowcountmsg;?>

                    Sent Messages</p>

            </div>
```

Comment: Where does `$resultsent` come from?

Comment: @David: I edited my question with it. I forgot to put it there. Sorry.

Comment: `"INNER JOIN employees ON sentmessages.employee_id=employees.employee_id"` - According to the image from the database there *is* no `sentmessages.employee_id`, how is this query working at all?

Comment: @David: That is also my mistake I forgot to edit it here. The queries don't fire up any errors. I tried them all in phpMyAdmin.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I got my code to work. Turns out nothing was essentially wrong but the query. The foreign key was not the problem. I tested this by reuploading the original schema and ran into the same duplicate id issue. According to the documentation Foreign keys allow duplicates. I've noticed there's a new id getting generated in the employee table which explain the duplicates. It's normal behavior according to how the database is designed. The foreign key constraint id (which is the user.id=employees.id) takes over the normal row id which should display as follow 1-2-3-4-5. It's something I needed to fix on the user table.

Now for the names not getting displayed properly, it has something to do with the query not understanding who to display. I had to do magic to make it understand as follow:

**I had to write:**

```
  $toEmployeeidQ = mysqli_query($db,"SELECT * FROM sentmessages INNER JOIN employees ON sentmessages.fromEmployee_id=employees.employee_id WHERE username = '$user_check'");
  $rowemployeeid = mysqli_fetch_array($toEmployeeidQ,MYSQLI_ASSOC);
  $session_toEmployeeid = $rowemployeeid['toEmployee_id'];
```

**then pass the variable in the query to get the names:**

```
 <td data-th="To">   
              <?php $toEmployee_idfnln = "SELECT first_name, last_name FROM `employees` INNER JOIN sentmessages ON employees.employee_id=sentmessages.toEmployee_id WHERE employees.employee_id='$session_toEmployeeid'";$resulfnln=mysqli_query($db,$toEmployee_idfnln);$displaynames = $resulfnln->fetch_assoc();?>
            <?php echo $displaynames['first_name'];?>  <?php echo $displaynames['last_name'];?>

      </td>
```